Answering WhatsApp Messages With Twilio and Flask
I have set up a Flask application with Twilio to send response via WhatsApp when someone sends a message to it. I already have a domain name, an EC2 instance on AWS, a public IP bound to that instance, and the Flask application running on port 8080. I am able to retrieve the message only when executed the curl -v <domain_name>:8080/whatsapp. But when I try sending a message to Twilio's phone number, it does not send a reply back. Below are the code and the response from the website when accessing it.
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/whatsapp", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def whatsapp_reply():
    response = MessagingResponse()
    response.message("Thank you for contacting us via WhatsApp!")
    return str(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

curl -v <domain_name>:8080/whatsapp:
*   Trying <EC2_public_ip>:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <domain_name> (<EC2_public_ip>) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /whatsapp HTTP/1.1
> Host: <domain_name>:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Werkzeug/3.1.3 Python/3.12.3
< Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2024 02:02:57 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 119
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Message>Thank you for contacting us via WhatsApp!</Message></Response>

Also, the messages on Programmable Messaging Logs (Monitoring > Logs > Messaging) are with Failed status with error code 30008 (Unknown error).

I have also set the website on Sandbox Settings (Develop > Messaging > Try it out > Send a WhatsApp message > Sandbox Settings). I tried providing like <domain_name>:8080/whatsapp and also <EC2_public_ip>:8080/whatsapp but both did not work when I tried sending the message on WhatsApp. It works when I execute the curl command or when I acces the website on the browser.
update (2024-11-14):
Below are the Error Logs page. All of them related to error 11200.



Your screenshot shows the Messaging Logs. Can you check the error logs instead if you find an answer there? https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/debugging-tools#error-logs

@IObert I have updated the content to include the error logs and the most frequent error (11200)

It seems your server is not returning the right document. From here I can't say what the problem is but I'd recommend to go through the list of possible solutions

It is strange because I am able to receive the message if I execute the curl command. Would you know which port Twilio's API use so that I can enable it on the security group?

It's regular HTTPS
